# What is in a Laravel application are Menu::render(), Assets::render(), Notify::render()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm working on a Laravel app that I haven't coded. I need to do some modifications and in my Blade templates I see some code like this:

```
 {!! Menu::render('client', 1, 1) !!}
```

```
{!! Assets::renderCss() !!}
```

```
{!! Notify::render() !!}
{!! Assets::renderJs() !!}
```

I understand that it's used to link some code like stylesheets, Javascript or a menu but I can't find these functions. I searched a little in the Laravel documentation but got no results. Are there some custom functions in my app?

The development environment is not very convenient and I can't search into the whole files. I wanted to modify the related menu and I didn't find the files where I have to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/app.php, you'll see a list of class aliases/facades:

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
    'Menu' => App\Facades\Menu::class,
    // ...
],
```

In this example, `App\Facades\Menu` would be the file app/Facades/Menu.php. If you can't find the listed file path, it's likely from a vendor file. For example, you'll probably see `'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,` which comes with Laravel and is documented in the [main Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache) and the [Laravel API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Cache.html). Packages may also be autodiscovered as of Laravel 5.5, so check your composer.json for what third-party libraries you're using.